# Is class contructor has undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11

My following class has undefined behaviour? I think its well defined becouse I m passing constructor arguments by reference. am I right?

```
class C
{
  int* elem;
  public:
    C(int s[]) :elem(s){}; // Array arguments passed by reference, so its well defined?
    void Print()
    {
      cout << elem[1] << endl;
    }
    ~C()
    {
       delete[] elem; 
    }
};
int main()
{
    C x(new int[2]{1,3});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't `delete [] elem;` in destructor, you leak memory

Comment: What behavior do you have ? Also as noticed above you should add destructor

Comment: Where is the undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's well-defined; you're creating an array, passing a valid pointer to the constructor (which takes a pointer, despite looking as though it takes an array), storing that pointer, and then accessing a valid array element through it.

The only problem is the memory leak - you never delete the array.

**UPDATE** Now you've added a destructor to delete the array, the class is very dangerous - if you copy it, then both copies will try to delete the same array. That *will* cause undefined behaviour. You need to either prevent copying, or implement it correctly, per the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722). You'll also get undefined behaviour if the pointer isn't to an array created with `new[]`.

Once you've learnt how to manage resources by hand, and how difficult it is to get all the details right, you would usually use a library class to do it for you. In this case, `std::vector<int>` would be ideal. Doing this is sometimes called the "Rule of Zero" (as mentioned in the comments), as it removes the need to write your own destructor or copy/move semantics at all - they all come from the class(es) you're using, which someone has already implemented correctly.

Comment: ...or rather Rule of Five, or rather Rule of Zero.

Comment: Or if you pass it a pointer to anything that is not a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @Griwes: Indeed, the Rule of Zero (use classes that already have correct semantics rather than implementing them yourself) is better. There isn't really a Rule of Five, at least as far as correctness is concerned; move semantics are something to think about for efficiency, not necessary for correctness.

Comment: sir it is passed by reference? becouse i think i read it long time ago from the book deitel's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312970/arrays-passed-by-reference-by-default

Comment: Read the first answer of the question you linked.

Comment: @VitoCarleone: The array is converted to a pointer, which gives a similar effect to passing by reference but without actually using references.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, you still need to define a move ctor and assignment operator if you have a raw resource in your class, since default moving will *copy* the resource handle and lead to freeing it twice. So yes, there really is a Rule of Five.

Comment: @Griwes: Once you've given the class safe copy semantics, it automatically has safe move semantics. Whether to give it different move semantics is a separate concern; so there's only a Rule of Five if you complicate matters by bundling both concerns together. But I suppose some people like to leap straight to a solution without breaking the problem down, so my opinion is only my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

There's no undefined behavior in your code. Also, you're not passing by reference, you're passing pointers by value.

Comment: realy? i was thinking In c++ arrays hidden passed by reference.

Comment: References and pointers are different things. And arrays are passed by values; the type is then a pointer type.

Comment: @VitoCarleone Passing an array by means of simply using its name, passes a pointer to its first element. This is often described as "arrays decay to pointers." But in your case, this isn't what happens anyway. You are passing a pointer to begin with (the `new` operator returns a pointer.) Also, the argument of your constructor, `int s[]`, is just syntactic sugar for `int* s`. The compiler sees it as a declaration of a pointer, not of an array.